# Using WITH SQL Query with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, with-statement

I have tried to rewrite the below query, so that it will work in a PHP page, but I have not been able to find any documentation on how the ";WITH" statement can be used in PHP, or how to make the same effect with a valid PHP Query.. The Query works perfect when executet in MS SQL 2008 R2 Management Studio, but it gives errors when I try to load it into MSSQL PHP Generator from SQLMaestro.

**The query is:**

```
;WITH UserStars AS
(
    SELECT a.username, ROUND(AVG(CAST(b.stars AS FLOAT)),1) Stars
    FROM score b
    JOIN game_users a ON a.id = b.game_users_id
    GROUP BY a.username
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN Stars < 1.4 THEN 'StarAmount1'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1.4 AND 2.4 THEN 'StarAmount2'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 2.4 AND 3.4 THEN 'StarAmount3'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 3.4 AND 4.4 THEN 'StarAmount4'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 4.4 AND 5.0 THEN 'StarAmount5' ELSE 'AnotherStarAmount' END         StarAmount,
        COUNT(*) Users
FROM UserStars
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Stars < 1.4 THEN 'StarAmount1'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1.4 AND 2.4 THEN 'StarAmount2'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 2.4 AND 3.4 THEN 'StarAmount3'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 3.4 AND 4.4 THEN 'StarAmount4'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 4.4 AND 5.0 THEN 'StarAmount5' ELSE 'AnotherStarAmount' END
```

Could someone point me in the right direction, so that the same query could be used in both PHP and in MS SQL 2008 R2 management studio?

Comment: Why aren't you using a stored procedure? PHP shouldn't care about the syntax used to derive results, as long as it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Stars < 1.4 THEN 'StarAmount1'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1.4 AND 2.4 THEN 'StarAmount2'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 2.4 AND 3.4 THEN 'StarAmount3'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 3.4 AND 4.4 THEN 'StarAmount4'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 4.4 AND 5.0 THEN 'StarAmount5' ELSE 'AnotherStarAmount' END         StarAmount,
        COUNT(*) Users
FROM (SELECT a.username, ROUND(AVG(CAST(b.stars AS FLOAT)),1) Stars
    FROM score b
    JOIN game_users a ON a.id = b.game_users_id
    GROUP BY a.username) UserStars
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Stars < 1.4 THEN 'StarAmount1'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1.4 AND 2.4 THEN 'StarAmount2'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 2.4 AND 3.4 THEN 'StarAmount3'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 3.4 AND 4.4 THEN 'StarAmount4'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 4.4 AND 5.0 THEN 'StarAmount5' ELSE 'AnotherStarAmount' END
```

Comment: Hi aF .. It works just perfect, in both Management Studio and in PHP.. Thanks alot for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not an altogether intuitive approach, but a different way to skin the cat without all the `CASE` expressions:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        c = game_users_id, 
        [avg] = AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(2,1), stars))
    FROM score
    GROUP BY game_users_id
), 
y AS
(
    SELECT StarAmount = 'StarAmount' 
        + LEFT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(2,1), [avg]+.6), 1)
        FROM x
)
SELECT StarAmount, Users = COUNT(*)
    FROM y
    GROUP BY StarAmount
    ORDER BY StarAmount;
```